# Laravel query builder - Select all where another table has their ID

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Basically, I'm trying to select everything from a table using Query Builder if there's a record in another table that meets some conditions. At the moment I have the code below, however it's very slow on a table with 100K rows.

```
 $result=  [];

    $customers = (array)DB::table('customers')->where('lastName','LIKE', Input::get('letter').'%')->orderBy('lastName','ASC')->get();

    foreach($customers as $k => $v)
    {
        if(DB::table('orders')->where('disabled','=','')->where('customerId','=',$v->id)->where('status','!=',0)->count() > 0)
        {
            array_push($result, $v);
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated! At the moment this times out after 5 minutes.

Comment: Have you tried using eager loading?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you're running one query to fetch customers and then a query for every customer to fetch related orders. If you have many customers it will result in a high number of queries you need to execute.

You can do this with a single query by joining those 2 tables.

This will do the trick:

```
//get all customers
$results = DB::table('customers')
  //filter customers by lastName
  ->where('customers.lastName','LIKE', Input::get('letter').'%')
  //take only customers that have orders matching criteria below
  ->join('orders', function($query) {
    //link customer to their orders
    $join->on('orders.customerId', '=', 'customers.id');
    //consider only enabled orders
    $join->where('orders.disabled','=','');
    //consider only orders where status != 0
    $join->where('orders.status','!=',0);
  })
  //if customer has multiple orders matching criteria 
  //they will be returned multiple time, so you need to group by
  //customers.id to get only one row per customer
  ->groupBy('customers.id')
  //order by customers last name
  ->orderBy('customers.lastName','ASC')
  ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for this, however it returns customers who do not have orders that meet the criteria. Anyway to not include those?

Comment: It can't be, it's an inner join so if no order matches the customer won't be returned. Could you replace get() with toSql(), dump the $results and paste here? Let's see what SQL is being generated

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
$data = Customer::with('Order') -> where('lastName','like',$name) -> whereExists(function($query){
$query->select(DB::raw(1)) -> from('orders')
 ->whereRaw('orders.customer_id= customer.id')
 ->where('disabled','=','')
 ->where('status','!=',0);
})-> orderBy('lastname','ASC')  -> get() ->toArray();
```